# What does $.expr[':'] means in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was looking at [bootstrap-select plugin](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) source code and I saw this line:

```
$.expr[':'].icontains = function(obj, index, meta) {
    return $(obj).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(meta[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

I'm curious what does `$.expr[':']` mean here?

Comment: *"here, is ':' key of an array?"* — No, you can use square brackets to index into objects as well, not only arrays.

Comment: The downvotes are because 1. since it is a duplicate, the question lacks research effort and 2. this is not the place to ask a question this broad.

Comment: @Anonymous I don't deserve a downvote for this because 1. Questions are not same and even it doesn't contain a goog answer and 2. I tried to search for it and I couldn't find result for my question, that why I asked it.

Comment: @Anonymous Seriously take a look at answers of the question you are pointing at? Does it really answers the question?!

Comment: Yes, they do.  Plus, if it didn't, you should have mentioned it in the question and explained why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's jQuery's way of creating a custom expression

```
$.expr[':'].icontains = function(obj, index, meta) {
    return $(obj).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(meta[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};
```

can be used as

```
$('.elements:icontains(text)')
```

It's a case-insensitive version of `:contains`

In other words, you can create any pseudo selector you want with `$.expr[':']`, lets try another one

```
$.expr[':'].christmas = function(obj, index, meta) {
    return $(obj).text().toLowerCase().indexOf('christmas') !== -1
}

$('.elements:christmas').addClass('xmas');
```

This would only select elements containing `christmas`

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/z8qn5/)

Comment: Literally 5 more seconds... Mr. Burns you are a quick gun for sure.

Comment: @SterlingArcher - Oh, not really, the number of answers I write, that I never get to post, just because someone beats me with two liners, is stunning. I'm actually not a very fast typer, nor a native english speaker, but I get lucky sometimes.

Comment: And that's not a very good duplicate ?

Comment: Sorry for off topic, but I would actually never guessed you're not a native speaker. You are very clear! (impressive!)

Comment: @adeneo Thanks man. I didn't deserve a downvote but your answer is complete. :D